# Anyway to prevent an object from being linked to a index in an array (python OOP A level)

Tags: python, chess

```
def makeMove(self, move):
    print (move.pieceMoved.row,move.pieceMoved.col,move.pieceMoved.moved)'''thisline'''
        self.positions[move.initialRow][move.initialCol] = "00"
        self.positions[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved
        self.positions[move.endRow][move.endCol].row = move.endRow # updates the piece moved' position
        self.positions[move.endRow][move.endCol].col = move.endCol
        #changes inital move flag to false if piece moved was a pawn (might use similar later for king and rook
        if isinstance(move.pieceMoved, Pawn):
            self.positions[move.endRow][move.endCol].moved = True    
        self.move_log.append(move) # log it incase we need to undo it later
        print (move.pieceMoved.row,move.pieceMoved.col,move.pieceMoved.moved) ''' this line'''
        self.white_turn = not self.white_turn #switches turn
```

I'm trying to code a chess program for my school project. Right now I'm just focussing on pawn moves to start. The problem I'm having is that the move object (contains things like piece(another object) moved, start square, end square etc) I'm passing in's attributes are changing when I change the value of self.positions[move.endRow][move.endCol] (which is a 2d array representing the chess board). Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Also the reason I think the move object attributes' are changing is that the two print statements marked """this line""" give different outputs. See attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC2uH.png)

I tried letting `temp = move`  and then making `self.positions[move.endRow][move.endCol] = temp.pieceMoved` but it didnt work as the two print statements still differed

To clarify self is a class called Gamestate

```
class GameState():

    def __init__(self):
        #board is an 8 by 8 2d list, each element of the list has 2 characters
        #the first character would represent the colour "b" for "black" and "w" for "white"
        #the second chr would represent the type of piece
        #"00" represents an empty space with no piece
        self.positions = [
                ['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
                ['bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP'],
                ['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00'],
                ['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00'],
                ['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00'],
                ['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00'],
                ['wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP'],
                ['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR'],
             ]
        self.white_turn = True
        self.move_log = []
        piece_construct = {"R" : Rook, "N" : Knight, "B" : Bishop, "Q" : Queen, "K" : King, "P" : Pawn,
            }
        for row in range(len(self.positions)):
             for col in range (len(self.positions[row])):
                 if self.positions[row][col] != "00":
                     self.positions[row][col] = (piece_construct[ (self.positions[row][col]) [1] ]) ( (self.positions[row][col]) , (row,col) )
```

Each piece has its own class but the only one I've really defined so far is the Pawn class

```
class Piece():

    def __init__(self, label, square):
        self.colour = label[0]
        self.title =  label 
        self.row = square[0]  
        self.col = square[1] 

        
class Pawn(Piece):
    def __init__(self, label, square):
        super().__init__(label, square)
        self.moved = False
```

The reason I don't want the move.piecemoved object's attributes to change is because its what I'm using in the undomove function which would have meant I didnt have to worry about the moved flag changing for  certain pieces

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more of your code to make a minimally reproducable example others can run (for example, what is `self` in this context?), but based on what I can see it makes sense those values would update as they did. With the board being rows 0 to 7, the pawn started on row 6, and it moved forward two spaces to row 4, and the `moved` boolean was set to True. While `move` itself didn't update, the values of row, column and moved attributes on `move.piecemoved` were updated.

Comment: I have updated what the code means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the copy module to make sure the position array was storing a copy of the move object so that when it was changed it doesnt affect the move object. (I didn't know that python links by Ref when using "=" for objects)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to follow up on your update earlier, but you're correct its a reference issue.  In Python, every variable is actually an object reference - even primitives like ints and floats are actually objects behind the scenes.  The main difference is between mutable and immutable objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wouldnt have realised that the objects were linked without your comment!